# initilize array in class constructor or when defined?

Tags: php

I have a $rawText class property that is supposed to be array. It's assigned a value during object construction, however the value may not be found so the variable remains without a value.

```
class TextProcessor {
    public $rawText;
    public function __construct($idText) {
        if ($idText !== NULL) {
            $this->$rawText = $this->getRawText();
        }
    }
}
```

Do I need to assign an empty array then?
public function __construct($idText) {

```
if ($idText !== NULL) {
    $this->$rawText = $this->getRawText(); 
} else {
    $this->$rawText = Array();
}
```

Or maybe it's even better to assign empty array when the property is defined?

```
class TextProcessor {
        public $rawText = Array();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 class TextProcessor {
        public $rawText = array();
        public function __construct($idText) {
            if (! empty($idText)) {
                $this->rawText = $this->getRawText();
            }
        }
    }
```

I think that's what you trying to do.

Comment: This way if `$idText` is empty, `rawText` is left uninitialized.

Comment: if `$idText` is empty, then `rawText` is not uninitialized. it'll be just an empty array

Comment: Yes, but it has to be defined as empty array in the first place, right?

Comment: So this is my question, should it be initialized as empty array when defined public `$rawText = Array();` ?

Comment: if you don't pre-initialize you could do the same in constructor using `else` statement. It's almost same. However, I think the common convention is not to initialize it first, but initialize it on constructor.

Comment: _if you don't pre-initialize you could do the same in constructor using else statement_ - that's exactly my question - which approach is better :). It seems that you've answered it with this: _I think the common convention is not to initialize it first, but initialize it on constructor_. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the construct method is used to define some variables private usually. If you want to give $rawText a new value, after you instantiate this class, you can write a set property method to change its value.